# Can I develop a controller on airconsole with scaled down version of what is on the main screen?

Tags: airconsole

My goal is to create some simple dice games, that show a more involved scoreboard and all other players on the main screen, but a general status of whose turn it is and scoreboard on the controller when it's not the players turn. That way you wouldn't need to see the main screen in order to play, but the main screen would still add value if you could see it. Anyone have any input on this?

Comment: Show us examples or code please

Answer (score 0):

This is generally possible, yes. Your question is very vague and the answer depends on what tools you intend to work with. Unity WebGL cannot be rendered on phones so far, but if you use JS based game creation tools, you can show whatever you like on the controller and main screen.